# Почему данные сессии выводятся в адресной строке браузера после отработки формы?

Tags: laravel

подскажите пожалуйста что не так?
есть форма на странице:

```
<form action="/pro-nas" method="PUT">
       @csrf
       @method('PUT')
       <select name="tema">
          <option value="{{$light}}">світла</option>
          <option value="{{$dark}}">темна</option>
       </select>
       <button type="submit">ttt</button>
    </form>
```

есть роут :  Route::resource('pro-nas', 'PronasController');

и контроллер:

```
class PronasController extends Controller
```

{

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    
    $light = 'pro-nas.css';
    $dark = 'pro-nas2.css';
    $tema = $request->input('tema');
    session(['tema' => $tema]);
    
    return view('pro-nas', compact('light','dark','tema'));
}
```

}

я хочу чтоб данные input сохранились в сессию после срабатывания формы и они сохраняются но урл страници меняется, к нему добавляются данные сессии получается так: mysite/pro-nas?_token=v0O2BqrCaR0j4HkGqqJuVc9tJvhtXXokaogc4rgn&_method=PUT&tema=pro-nas.css как убрать эти данные из адресной строки и сохранить их в сесии правильно?

Answer (score 1):

`method="PUT"` -> `method="POST"`

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `session(['tema' => $tema]);` вставьте:

`$request->session()->push(['tema' => $tema']);`

и вот статья для Вас по правильной работе с сессиями в Laravel 5: [ссылка](https://laravel.demiart.ru/laravel-sessions/)

Comment: делаю именно так как Вы написали и как написано в документации вот: public function index(Request $request)
    {
     
     $light = 'pro-nas.css';
     $dark = 'pro-nas2.css';
     $tema = $request->input('tema');
     $request->session()->push(['tema' => $tema]);
     $value = $request->session()->get('tema');
     return view('pro-nas', compact('light','dark','value'));
    }  и получаю ошибку: production.ERROR: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Session\Store::push(), 1 passed in